# CentOS 7: Error while installing dovecot-mysql package

Tags: mysql, centos7, dovecot

We have postfix (2.10.1) and dovecot (2.2.36.4 (baf9232c1)) pre-installed in the CentOS server that we purchased. When we try to install dovecot-mysql driver as part of configuring mail server using postfix, dovecot, we get this conflict thrown as error -
Error: plesk-dovecot conflicts with 1:dovecot-2.2.36-3.el7_7.1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Please let us know how to install this package so that we can use MySQL to authenticate users. We have a similar setup working fine in CentOS 6, but facing this problem while migrating to CentOS 7. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Voting to move this question to superuser.stackexchange.com, because it's a system admin question, it has nothing to do with code.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that site. Posted the question at that site now.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict was between plesk-dovecot and the dovecot-mysql that I was trying to install through yum. Apparently DB support does not come default. So the only option was to uninstall Postfix and Dovecot that came with Plesk and install both afresh using yum. The config files had to be re-copied and it worked.